# RSpec method fails after Rails 5.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, omniauth

I just upgraded an old app from Rails 3.2 to Rails 5.1.6. This test used to work but fails now:

```
# spec/requests/social_sign_ups_spec.rb
describe 'Twitter sign ups:' do

  before(:each)  do
    OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
  end

  it 'Logs in new user:' do
    visit new_session_path
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
        'provider' => 'twitter',
        'uid' =>  Twitter_identifier,
        'info' => {
             'name' => 'squiddio',
             'image' => "http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/568944504166567936/UcqveaGp_normal.png"
         },
        'credentials' => {
            "token" =>  Twitter_token,
            "secret" => Twitter_token_secret
        }
    })

    click_link 'Twitter log-in'
    # this is where I get the callback error in the server- see logs below


  end
end
```

looking at the server logs:

```
tail -f log/test.log
# .......
# Completed 200 OK in 2268ms (Views: 2263.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
# Started GET "/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-08 08:32:01 -0700
# Started GET "/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=<some token>" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-08 08:32:01 -0700   

# ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/oauth/authenticate"):

# .......
```

Can anyone figure out why the callback from Rack is:

```
/oauth/authenticate
```

instead of the standard:

```
/auth/twitter/callback
```

I get in development and production?

Additional info:

```
bundle show rails  # -> rails-5.1.6
bundle show rspec-rails # -> rspec-rails-3.7.2
```